# Struts 2 workflow interceptor and actions that do not have an INPUT result

Tags: java, struts2, workflow, struts2-interceptors

If I understand, the Struts 2 interceptor stack correctly, the workflow interceptor looks to see if any validation failures have been reported by the validation interceptor. If it finds that there *have* been  validation failures, it returns ( by default ) `Action.INPUT`

If this is the case, what happens if the Action that is being executed does not have an `INPUT` result defined in its `struts.xml` configuration?

Comment: This seems easy to determine by trying it, but hopefully it's also fairly obvious-you'll get an error saying the result isn't defined. A global result can be helpful for catching these and at least presenting something a user can understand, but it's a development-level bug if it ever happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it returns INPUT, and there is no result defined for that (and no general result), you'll get an error page that says something like

```
 No result defined for type INPUT and action <action name>.
```

You can define a general page that will always be shown for 'INPUT', but the better solution is that if you have a validate() method, it's usually a good idea to define an INPUT result to go back.  Even if you don't explicitly do any validation, things like a non-integer value being passed to an integer field can cause that result, so it's a good idea to define it.

Answer (score 0):

`INPUT` result is used by default, you could always override it via setting parameter to interceptor `inputResultName`.

```
<interceptor-ref name="workflow">
   <param name="inputResultName">error</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

Further clarification and reference to [`workflow` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/default-workflow-interceptor.html).

In the example above the action doesn't have an `INPUT` result and if action errors or field errors found then result `ERROR` will return.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ValidationWorkflowAware` interface to define result name per action

or

You can use `InputConfig` annotation to change the result name per action programatically

or

With upcoming new release of Struts version 2.3.15 it will be also possible to use `ValidationErrorAware` interface, actions can be notified about error and can change returned result name: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4071