# Validation in struts2 using annotation

Tags: jsp, validation, struts2

I'm getting the following exception as soon as the page is loaded while implementing validation in Struts2 (2.3.16).

```
Dec 24, 2013 1:43:52 AM org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher error
SEVERE: Could not find action or result
/TestStruts/admin_side/test.action
No result defined for action actions.TestAction and result input
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:373)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:275)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1822)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

**The action class:**

```
@Namespace("/admin_side")
@ResultPath("/WEB-INF/content")
public final class TestAction extends ActionSupport implements Serializable, ValidationAware
{
    @Autowired
    private final transient TransporterService transporterService=null;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String SUCCESS = "success";

    private String name;
    private String email;

    @Action(value = "test", results = {
    @Result(name="success", location="Test.jsp"),
    @Result(name = "error", location = "Test.jsp"),
    }, interceptorRefs = @InterceptorRef("validationWorkflowStack"))
    public String test() throws Exception
    {
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @RequiredFieldValidator(message = "The name is required")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    @RequiredStringValidator(type= ValidatorType.FIELD, message = "The email is required.")
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

**The `Test.jsp` page:**

```
<s:actionerror />
<s:fielderror />

<s:form namespace="/admin_side" action="test" validate="true">

    <s:textfield id="name" name="name" label="Enter your name"/>
    <s:textfield id="email" name="email" label="Enter your email"/>
    <s:submit id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit"/>

</s:form>
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: After all the fields are checked, if any of them failed to validate then the string "INPUT" is returned and the execute() method is never run. Your annotations account for SUCCESS and ERROR (although you don't generate the ERROR string... should probably replace ERROR with INPUT and your issue will go away). Also the struts2 tags should automatically display errors unless you're using the simple theme (which I use) in such a case the s2 field error tag should generally use the name attribute so you can set a specific field error beside the UI element (not required of course but nice).

Comment: @Quaternion : It worked with that change. May add as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/16691360/573032

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer added at request of OP, with regard to solution in comment.

After all the fields are checked, if any of them failed to validate then the string "INPUT" is returned and the execute() method is never run.

Your annotations account for SUCCESS and ERROR (although you don't generate the ERROR string... should probably replace ERROR with INPUT and your issue will go away).

Also the struts2 tags should automatically display errors unless you're using the simple theme (which I use) in such a case the s2 field error tag should generally use the name attribute so you can set a specific field error beside the UI element (not required of course but nice).